# Rspec test to check input is within range 1-4 works once then fails

Tags: ruby, rspec, range

My rspec test fails no matter what my input is. 
I am running a test to make sure input is between 1-4 
And it only seems to work when I input 3?

```
require 'order'
describe Order do
  it 'gets dish input' do
    order = Order.new
    allow(order.input).to receive(:gets).and_return(:name)
  end

  it 'checks input' do
    order = Order.new
    expect(order.input).to eq (1..4)
  end 
end
```

Calling order.rb

```
class Order
  def initialize
    input
  end

  def input
    puts 'please select the number of your dish'
    gets.chomp
  end

  def valid_range? input
    input.to_i.between?(1..4)
  end
end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your `Order` class as :

```
class Order
  attr_reader :dish_number

  def initialize
    @dish_number = input.to_i
  end

  def valid_dish?
    dish_number.between?(1, 4)
  end

  private

  def input
    puts 'please select the number of your dish'
    gets.chomp
  end
end
```

And its corresponding spec should be :

```
require_relative '../order.rb'

describe Order do
  it 'gets dish number as input' do
    allow_any_instance_of(Order).to receive(:input).and_return("1")
    order = Order.new
    expect(order.dish_number).to eq(1)
  end

  it 'checks valid dish' do
    allow_any_instance_of(Order).to receive(:input).and_return("1")
    order = Order.new
    expect(order).to be_valid_dish
  end 
end
```

Result is :

```
[arup@Ruby]$ rspec spec/order_spec.rb
..

Finished in 0.00946 seconds (files took 0.12904 seconds to load)
2 examples, 0 failures
[arup@Ruby]$
```

As [*@myron*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320055/rspec-test-to-check-input-is-within-range-1-4-works-once-then-fails/29320707?noredirect=1#comment46928270_29320707) said, here is the DRY version of the code :

```
require_relative '../order.rb'

describe Order do
  def new_order(input)
    order = Order.new
    allow(order).to receive(:input).and_return(input)
    order
  end

  it 'gets dish number as input' do
    expect(new_order("1").dish_number).to eq(1)
  end

  it 'checks valid dish' do
    expect(new_order("1")).to be_valid_dish
  end 
end
```

Comment: Arup Thank you! was a big help! Sorry I can't help with Drying it out.

Comment: You can reduce the duplication by extracting a helper method: https://gist.github.com/myronmarston/d9b74961cb5e5d81e6b4